# How to club dates together and show their data in java or in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, hashmap, set

I am retriving this json in android and i want to show data as per date(tabs with viewpager)

e.g.- **23(Tab1)**: 1) id-9854359 2) id-9854360 || **24(Tab2)** id-9854361 2) id-9854360

every tab has recyclerview items that i want to show data for, but the problem is this i want to club date together and show data according to that. I have tried using hashmap, map...but still no luck.

```
[
    {
    "end_time": "2020-01-23 01:45:00+00:00",
    "is_booked": false,
    "is_expired": false,
    "slot_id": 9854359,
    "start_time": "2020-01-23 01:30:00+00:00",
    "username": null
    },
    {
    "end_time": "2020-01-23 02:05:00+00:00",
    "is_booked": false,
    "is_expired": false,
    "slot_id": 9854360,
    "start_time": "2020-01-23 01:50:00+00:00",
    "username": null
    },
    {
    "end_time": "2020-01-24 02:45:00+00:00",
    "is_booked": false,
    "is_expired": false,
    "slot_id": 9854359,
    "start_time": "2020-01-24 02:30:00+00:00",
    "username": null
    },
    {
    "end_time": "2020-01-24 03:05:00+00:00",
    "is_booked": false,
    "is_expired": false,
    "slot_id": 9854359,
    "start_time": "2020-01-24 02:50:00+00:00",
    "username": null
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Covert JSON to classes.** As far as I know, in Android it is standard practice to use GSON.

```
class Entity {
    String end_time
    boolean is_booked
    boolean is_expired
    long slot_id;
    String start_time;
    String username;
}

List<Entity> entities = gson.fromJson(yourJsonAsString), Entity.class);
```

**Extract date and group by date.** I suggest using java Stream API, since it is made just for tasks like this:

```
Map<String, List<Entity>> grouppedByDate = 
    entities.stream().collect(
        Collectors.grouppingBy(entity -> entity.end_time.split(" ")[0])
    )
```

**Create tab view with each tab containing list view.**

For tab adapter use collection `grouppedByDate.entries()` where `entry.getKey()` is date of the entities in this tab and `entry.getValue()` is list of entries.

Comment: Hey man, how would we create map for time(Morning,afternoon,evening) and List<Entity> ?

Comment: @hiashutoshsingh you have to pass a function that takes entity and returns `"morning","afternoon" or "evening"` to `grouppingBy`

Comment: @hiashutoshsingh even better: define an enum for MORNING... instead of using strings

Comment: @alijazerzen Thanks , I have figured it out.